# Copying files with the names having a number within a range

Tags: regex, powershell, copy

I am unfamiliar with Powershell (besides its existence and way to run a powershell commands). I have a folder **source**. Inside that folder I have several files:

```
image_001.jpg
image_002.jpg
...
...
image_250.jpg
...
...
...
image_8000.jpg
```

Out of these I want to select specific images, say from **image_00001.jpg - image_00250.jpg** and copy them to destination folder say, **destination**

Can anyone tell me the commands for powershell to do that?

I apologize for such a noob question. I don't know a thing about powershell though my intuition says this might be the easiest task to achieve.

**Note:** I tried to understand the other answer about doing similar task but due to lack of my knowledge of **regex**, I was unable to comprehend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
cls

$source = "<your source>"
$destination = "<your destination>" 

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if ($i.Name -match "image_(000\d\d|001\d\d|002[0-4]\d|00250)\.jpg")
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
    }
}
```

Explanation for regex:

`000\d\d|001\d\d|002[0-4]\d|00250` matches the numbers from `00000-00250`

- `000\d\d` matches the pattern `000(any digit)(any digit)` i.e.. till `00099`
- `001\d\d` matches `001(any digit)(any digit)` i.e from `00100 to 00199`
- `002[0-4]\d` matches `002(any digit from 0 to 4)(any digit)` i.e from 00200 to 00249`
- `00250` matches literal `00250`
- `|` or operator.. to match any of the above specified patterns

Comment: It worked! One more thing, can you explain image_(000\d\d|00[1]\d\d|00[2][0-4]\d|00250)\.jpg ? I mean if I need to select images from 5000 - 8000, what is the thing to notice here?

Comment: @pulp_fiction check the update.. so.. if you need to select from 5000-8000, regex would be `[567]\d\d\d|8000`.. :)

Comment: I need to ask this : In your expression image_(000\d\d|00[1]\d\d|00[2][0-4]\d|00250)\.jpg  .What if I want all the images except this set. Is there any negate operator to achieve that in one go?

Comment: You can use negative lookahead: `image_(?!(000\d\d|001\d\d|002[0-4]\d|00250))\d{5}\.jpg`